# How to restrict users in Weblogic and OBIEE by IP?

Tags: oracle, weblogic, weblogic11g, oracle-bi

I have some users that they can connect to OBIEE from everywhere.

I would like to know, 
how to **allow**/**deny** connections to BI by **IP**.

Comment: Have a look at the product documentation about security and connection filters : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e13707/domain.htm#SECMG410

Answer (score 0):

The recommended architecture will be to use an Apache or OHS in the DMZ area. Webserver will connect with weblogic behind firewall. Apache can be used to allow/deny any IP/IP pattern